# Create a Trigger in Task Scheduler based on the addition of a row in an remote SQL DB

Tags: sql, event-handling

I am looking to trigger the execution of a sync program based on the additon of a new row in a remote SQL database. This will start a project ispac file that syncs our databases across our company. Is there a way to create this as a custom event? Right now we are triggering this on a timer which is not sufficent. Thank you.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (This will have a product specific solution.)

Comment: We are using Azure aka Microsoft SQL Server (RDBMS)